# ccl lisp on ubuntu: when I leave ccl it terminates the shell

Tags: ubuntu, common-lisp, digital-ocean, ccl

I'm using ccl (Clozure CL) 1.11.5 on on a digital ocean Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-124-generic x86_64) server. Works fine, but whenever I exit lisp, either by ^d or (quit), the linux shell terminates as well and I have to re-ssh to the server! I've tried this with both bash ignoreeof on and off -- same thing happens. Any clues what's going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: not really an explanation but an idea for a hotfix until you have the solution for the issue at hand: Have you tried running the console lisp in screen/tmux

Comment: Actually, I've been using a similar workaround to what you have suggested: I've taken to always just firing up an emacs, and operating entirely from an internal shell. I will give tmux a try, though. Thanks!